# libgdx, animatios dont scale on android

Tags: camera, libgdx

I was testing my app on android,
my app have 1 background image with 2 animations using TextureAtlas
it works fine on desctop, the sprite and the animations all scale but when I teste it on android, the sprite resize corretly but the animations dont resize at all

```
     constantes.VIRTUAL_WIDTH=1920;
constantes.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT=1080;

.....

    public static void show() {
 camera = new OrthographicCamera(constantes.VIRTUAL_WIDTH, constantes.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT); //Aspect Ratio Maintenance
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
                    texturafundo = new Texture("cenarios/penhasco.jpg");
                    spriteFundo = new Sprite(texturafundo);
                    spriteFundo.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

                // animations

                   textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("anima/rio.txt"));
                   animacao = new Animation(1/10f, textureAtlas.getRegions());

                  textureAtlas2 = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("anima/portal.txt"));
                  animacao2 = new Animation(1/10f, textureAtlas2.getRegions());
}
public void render(float delta) {
           // update camera
        camera.update();


        // set viewport
        Gdx.gl.glViewport((int) viewport.x, (int) viewport.y,
        (int) viewport.width, (int) viewport.height);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        elapsedTime+=delta;

          batch.begin();



            spriteFundo.draw(batch);
            //sesenha animacao 1
            batch.draw(animacao.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 0, 0);
            batch.draw(animacao2.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 788, 249);


        batch.end();

    }

    public void resize(int width, int height) {


           float aspectRatio = (float)width/(float)height;
            float scale = 1f;
            Vector2 crop = new Vector2(0f, 0f);

            if(aspectRatio > constantes.ASPECT_RATIO) {
                scale = (float) height / (float) constantes.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT;
                crop.x = (width - constantes.VIRTUAL_WIDTH * scale) / 2f;
            } else if(aspectRatio < constantes.ASPECT_RATIO) {
                scale = (float) width / (float) constantes.VIRTUAL_WIDTH;
                crop.y = (height - constantes.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT * scale) / 2f;
            } else {
                scale = (float) width / (float) constantes.VIRTUAL_WIDTH;
            }

            float w = (float) constantes.VIRTUAL_WIDTH * scale;
            float h = (float) constantes.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT * scale;
            viewport = new Rectangle(crop.x, crop.y, w, h);


    }
```

Comment: I test it on a laptop with less resolution than 1920x1080 and the same problem the animations arent in the right place and they are not scalled to the screen resolution, 1920x1080 is the game resolution, (the background resolution), its seams that is impossible to scale animation on  batch.draw(

Comment: it doesn't look like you're using libgdx viewports. I would read through this first https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports